# How to merge two key of one array into one key?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge two values of two keys within one key.
The array looks like this:

```
[PromotionIds] => Array (
    [PromotionId] => Array (
        [0] => Amazon PLCC Free-Financing Universal Merchant MP-rachmit-1507891499711
        [1] => Amazon PLCC Free-Financing Universal Merchant Script-1507895115492
        )
    )
```

But i want to merge the `[0]` and `[1]` key into the key `[PromotionID]`:

```
[PromotionIds] => Array (
    [PromotionId] => Amazon PLCC Free-Financing Universal Merchant MP-rachmit-1507891499711,Amazon PLCC Free-Financing Universal Merchant Script-1507895115492
    )
```

Comment: Try by Array_combine. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 0):

I think [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) method may help you:

```
<?php

$a = [
    123 => [
        "String1",
        "String2"
    ],
    234 => [
        "String3", 
        "String4",
        "String5"
    ]
];

foreach($a as $promotionId => $items) {
    $a[$promotionId] = implode($items, ',');
} 

var_dump($a);


//array(2) {
//  [123] =>
//      string(15) "String1,String2"
//  [234] =>
//      string(23) "String3,String4,String5"
//}
```

Comment: thanks for remembering me `implode()` it's helped me a lot

Comment: @PrAtikLochawala you are welcome! Please, accept my answer, if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$array = ['PromotionIds' => Array (
    'PromotionId' => Array (
        0 => 'Amazon PLCC Free-Financing Universal Merchant MP-rachmit-1507891499711',
        1 => 'Amazon PLCC Free-Financing Universal Merchant Script-1507895115492'
        )
    )];
$result = [];

foreach ($array['PromotionIds'] as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key]=implode(',', $value);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

the result would as you expected.